# Java : Keystate operation issue

Tags: java, java-me

I'm having a problem getting the screen to change to the image I want to display.

The image is a spritesheet which is set up as an array ( ie first screen is in array index 0 etc...)

I can change when I press the UP key and LEFT key and ENTER key, but the program will not display the correct image pressing the DOWN key.

I eventually want to discard the arrow key presses and subsituite them for numbers (the phone number keys ) 4 to return, 1,2,3 to go to certain pages and enter to go to the next page, if there is more information on a particular page.

```
    private void actOnKeyStates(int k) {
        if ((k & DOWN) != 0) {
            Title = false;
            HowToPlay = true;
            Controls = false;
            About = false;
        }
        if ((k & UP) != 0) {
            Title = false;
            HowToPlay = false;
            Controls = true;
            About = false;
        }

        if ((k & LEFT) != 0) {
            Title = true;
            HowToPlay = false;
            Controls = false;
            About = false;
        }

        if ((k & FIRE_PRESSED) != 0) {
            Title = false;
            HowToPlay = false;
            Controls = false;
            About = true;
        }
        update();

    }

    public void update() {
        if (Title) {
            Screen.setFrame(0);
        }
        if (HowToPlay) {
            Screen.setFrame(1);
        }
        if (Controls) {
            Screen.setFrame(4);
        }
        if (About) {
            Screen.setFrame(5);
        }

    }
```

I would appreciate any advice on the matter.

Comment: Not sure what's wrong, but I would suggest debugging and seeing what k's value actually is when you press down.

Answer (score 0):

First I think it would be better if you established a state for your game, rather than just using an increasing number of boolean values. Such as this:

```
public enum ScreenState { Title, HowToPlay, Controls, About }    
private ScreenState currentScreen = ScreenState.Title;

private void actOnKeyStates(int k) {
    if ((k & DOWN) != 0) {
        currentScreen = ScreenState.HowToPlay;
    }

    if ((k & UP) != 0) {
        currentScreen = ScreenState.Controls;
    }

    if ((k & LEFT) != 0) {
        currentScreen = ScreenState.Title;
    }

    if ((k & FIRE_PRESSED) != 0) {
        currentScreen = ScreenState.About;
    }

    update();
}

public void update() {
    switch(currentScreen) {
        case Title:       
            Screen.setFrame(0);
            break;
        case HowToPlay:
            Screen.setFrame(1);
            break;
        case Controls:
            Screen.setFrame(4);
            break;
        case About:
            Screen.setFrame(5);
            break;
     }
 }
```

The second thing you need to do is confirm that k & DOWN is being executed correctly when the DOWN arrow is pressed. Also confirm that the image you are looking for is correctly placed in the position `1` in your sprite sheet.